# PHP and MYSQL, Trying to send data to a data base

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am currently trying to send data from an HTML form (Proform.html) to a MYSQL database. I cannot figure out how to solve this problem that keeps occurring as I  am new to php the error message I keep receiving is.

> "Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\php\Proform.php on line 22"

It could be possable as I have used several different references to create this page of code that i have mixxed two different realeases of php. Though help would be appriciated Anyways code is as follows.

```
    <?php

$dbname='*****';
$dbhost='localhost';
$dbpass='******';
$dbuser='******';






$dbhandle = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass)
  or die("Unable to connect to MySQL");
echo "Connected to MySQL<br>";


//select a database to work with
$selected = mysql_select_db("ecig",$dbhandle)
  or die("Could not select examples");

$q = $dbhandle->query("INSERT INTO Persons (First_Name, Last_Name)

VALUES ('$_POST[First_Name]', yes)");



if (array_key_exists ('check_submit', $_POST )) 

echo "Your Name is : {$_POST['First_Name']}<br />";
echo "Your Second Name is : {$_POST['Second_Name']}<br />";
echo "Your Email Address is : {$_POST['Email_Address']}<br />";
echo "Your Password Is : {$_POST['Password']}<br />";

?>
```

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: FYI, you are also wide open to [SQL injections](http://stackoverflow.com/q/60174)

Comment: the connection string is made with mysql which does not support database calls as an object. if you want to use it, use mysql_fetch_array but mysql calls are deprecated. Instead, I suggest switching to mysqli with $con=mysqli_connect($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpass,$dbname);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a problem in your query

Why are you calling the query using the database connection string.

You have to call it like this:

```
$con=mysql_connect($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpass,$dbname);
$res=mysql_query("INSERT INTO Persons (First_Name, Last_Name) VALUES('$_POST[First_Name]', yes)");
mysql_close();
```

Comment: Hi i tried doing it this way and the other way but the data is not being submitting it into the form any ideas ?

Comment: There may be two types of Problem.You are getting any error there?

Comment: You simply add the or die(mysql_error()); at the end of the query and if you can got any type of error then i can help you.

Answer (score 0):

`mysql_connect` does not return any object .... so it does not have any function or property that you can access using `->` operator  . It returns a connection identifier

replace

```
$dbhandle->query("INSERT INTO Persons (First_Name, Last_Name)
VALUES ('$_POST[First_Name]', yes)");`
```

with

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO Persons (First_Name, Last_Name) 
VALUES ('$_POST[First_Name]', yes)")
```

I advice you to start learning mysqli or PDO since mysql functions are retarded and no longer maintained

Comment: you can see http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.mysql.php if you want to know further about mysql functions